# On Click browser's back button load back both the iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am new to HTML iframes.

My HTML code looks as following.

**`index.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change(content,content2) {

            top.iframe_b.location.href = content2;
            top.iframe_a.location.href = content;

        }    
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <a title="" href="#" onclick="change('a.html','b.html')"><div class="smallbox">Click meee</div></a>

        <div style="width: 30%; height: 100%; float:left">
            <iframe id="iframe_a" src="home.html" height="100%" width="100%" name="iframe_a"></iframe>  
        </div>

        <div style="width: 70%; height: 100%; float:right">
            <iframe id="iframe_b" src="dash.html" height="100%" width="100%" name="iframe_b" style="border-left: solid; border-left-color: black"></iframe>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body>
```

When I click on link `Click meee` then both the iframes `iframe_a` and `iframe_b` will render `a.html` and `b.html` pages respectively which is fine.

But when i click browser's back button then its changing only the `iframe_a` to load `home.html`. but the `iframe_b` is not changing. (Ad last change href was of `iframe_a` in the javascript code)

then on the second click it is changing the `iframe_b` and loading the  `dash.html` into it.

**I want both the `iframes` to switch to last page when click the browser's back button once only.**

Please suggest regarding this if its possible or any alternate solution will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need iframes?
If you want load some content to main html page you can do this much better with e.g. [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.  (Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element).

Comment: will I be able to load the last page on click of browser's back button? I don't think its possible with that

Comment: jquery load() works asynchronously so your index.html don't even change your location, but as i mentioned before if you want do any changes you can implement this by using some js code. If you want e.g show / hide some content after action e.g click, you can do this in many ways.